# timeout websocket connection in live

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs, serversocket

i was building a project with nest.js and flutter and i have impement websockets
and i was connecting on port 5003 in websocket
and everything was working and when i deployed the backend to railwasy.app it give me that error Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.196.232.237:5003
i tried to connect with

- ws://website-live-nestjs-production.up.railway.app:5003

```
@WebSocketGateway(5003, {
  path: '/',
  // pingInterval: 30000, // default 25e3
  // pingTimeout: 4000, // default 5e3
  serveClient: false,
})
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {

    prisma =new PrismaClient()

    wsClients=[];

  @WebSocketServer()
  private server: Server;
```

Comment: Please check you websocket is connect with live server or not.
If you are not able to connect you web socket server then this kind of error occur.

Comment: railway app host doesn't support websockets ?